# Limit of a complex function of a complex variable expressed in polar form

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I've got the complex function

$$f(t;z,\mu) = \mathrm{e}^{-z\sinh t-\mu t}$$

where $$t=R \mathrm{e}^{i\theta},\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$$ The function depends on two parameters, $$z>0, \mu \in \mathbf{C}$$ with $$\mathrm{Re}(\mu) > 0, \mathrm{Im}(\mu) < 0$$

I want Mathematica to calculate the limit $$R \to \infty$$ of this function (it should be zero), but I don't know how to proceed. Any hint?

I tried with the straightforward instructions

```
In[1]:= int = Exp[-z*Sinh[t] - \[Mu] *t] /. t -> R*Exp[i\[Theta]]

Out[1]= E^(-E^i\[Theta] R \[Mu] - z Sinh[E^i\[Theta] R])

In[2]:= Limit[int, R -> \[Infinity], 
 Assumptions -> {{z > 0}, {Re[\[Mu]] > 0}, {Im[\[Mu]] < 
     0}, {\[Theta] > 0}, {\[Theta] < \[Pi]/2}}]

Out[2]= ConditionalExpression[\[Infinity], \[Mu] \[Element] Reals && 
  E^i\[Theta] < 0 && z > 0]
```

obtaining a nonsensical conditional expression... How can the exponential of an imaginary number be less than zero - at least in the range I indicated in Assumpions? It looks like my assumptions are not taken into account.

Comment: Please add copy/pastable Mathematica code for the expression and constraints.

Comment: Dear Daniel, I did it.

Comment: The real part of that sinh can oscillate (plot it with theta set to `4*E/7`) so it would seem the limit does not exist in general.

Comment: I don't see the point. The limit should exist for any fixed value of theta, so at most the final result could be a function of theta. But I do I get Mathematica help me explore this? This is exactly what I was asking.

Comment: The point is that if the real part of the sinh oscillates and the oscillations increase without bound then there is no limit. Which is the gist of a response by @user64494.

Answer (score 1):

The limit under consideration does not exist except the case `\[Theta]=0`. Indeed, specifying the parameters and correcting a syntax error (`I*\[Theta]` instead of `i\[Theta]`) , we have

```
\[Theta] = Pi/4; \[Mu] = 1 - I; z = 1; 
int = Exp[-z*Sinh[t] - \[Mu]*t] /. t -> R*Exp[I*\[Theta]];
Limit[ComplexExpand[int], R -> \[Infinity]]
```

> $$\underset{R\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(e^{\left(-\sqrt{2}\right) R-\cos \left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \sinh \left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\right)} \cos \left(\sin \left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)-i e^{\left(-\sqrt{2}\right) R-\cos \left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \sinh \left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\right)} \sin \left(\sin \left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right) $$

and

```
MaxLimit[ComplexExpand[Re[-z*Sinh[t] - \[Mu]*t /. t -> R*Exp[I*\[Theta]]]], R -> \[Infinity]]
```

> $\infty$

```
MinLimit[ComplexExpand[Re[-z*Sinh[t] - \[Mu]*t /. t -> R*Exp[I*\[Theta]]]],R -> \[Infinity]]
```

> $-\infty$

Mathematica fails (So do I.) with

```
MaxLimit[ComplexExpand[int], R -> \[Infinity]]
```

Appendix.

```
ClearAll[z, \[Mu]]; \[Theta] = Pi/4; 
int = Exp[-z*Sinh[t] - \[Mu]*t] /. t -> R*Exp[I*\[Theta]];
MaxLimit[ComplexExpand[ Re[-z*Sinh[t] - (Re[\[Mu]] + I*Im[\[Mu]])*t /. 
t -> R*Exp[I*\[Theta]]]], R -> \[Infinity]]
```

> $\infty$

```
MinLimit[ComplexExpand[Re[-z*Sinh[t] - \[Mu]*t /. t -> R*Exp[I*\[Theta]]]],R -> \[Infinity]]
```

> $-\infty$